# Troubleshooting Rakuten Linksynergy affiliate links in mobile - purchased items not tracking

Tags: cookies, affiliate, third-party-cookies

Rakuten is a very frustrating network as their customer service team is abysmal in helping to troubleshoot an affiliate publisher's implementation. I am hoping there is someone out there that can help us.

We use Rakuten linksynergy links in our ios and android mobile app which when clicked opens a browser to the seller's product page.

We can see clicks registering on the Rakuten dashboard but never a sale. We have checked the following things in the browser setting:

-Allow cross-site tracking
-Allow cookies
-javascript is enabled

(incidentally Amazon affiliate links track perfectly in our system)

Ideas as to why it is not working? Places we should look to troubleshoot?